# Calculating the average each row and save into array

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to create the program to read each lines and calculate each line's average and store into array...For example, program will read first line, add all the numbers and divide by 24 to calculate the average which will be stored into Avg_list[1].
When I try to run the program, I encounter following error, I have no idea why it  doesn't work... Can someone identify the problem?

Code:  in Ksh

```
 c=0
 while read -r line ; do
     v=$line
     set -- $v    ((g=($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13+$14+$15+$16+$17+$18+$19+$20+$21+$22+$23+$24+$25+$26)/24))
      echo $g
      Avg_list[${c}]=$g
      ((c=c+1))
  done < daily.txt
```

daily.txt

```
CPU 55 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 55 54 54 55 56 57 54 57 54
CPEAK 56 56 57 55 58 56 56 56 57 55 60 56 55 56 55 56 58 55 57 56 63 56 72 57
RAM 97 97 97 97 97 96 96 96 96 96 96 93 91 89 86 84 90 90 95 97 97 97 97 97
RPEAK 97 97 97 97 97 97 96 96 96 96 96 96 92 90 91 81 94 89 97 97 97 97 97 97
```

Error note:

```
while read -r line ; do
        v=$line
        set -- $v
        ((g=($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13+$14+$15+$16+$17+$18+$19+$20+$21+$22+$23+$24+$25+$26)/24))
        echo $g
        Avg_list[${c}]=$g
        ((c=c+1))
done < daily.txt
+ 0< daily.txt
+ read -r line
+ v=CPU 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 55 54 54 55 56 57 54 57 54 54
+ set -- CPU 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 55 54 54 55 56 57 54 57 54 54
+ (( g=(54+54+54+54+54+54+54+54+CPU0+CPU1+CPU2+CPU3+CPU4+CPU5+CPU6+CPU7+CPU8+CPU9+540+541+542+543+544+545+546)/24 ))
PerformanceAM.sh[21]: g=(54+54+54+54+54+54+54+54+CPU0+CPU1+CPU2+CPU3+CPU4+CPU5+CPU6+CPU7+CPU8+CPU9+540+541+542+543+544+545+546)/24: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.
```

EDIT

```
    while read -r line ; do
    v=$line
    set -- $v
    ((g=${2}+${3}+${4}+${5}+${6}+${7}+${8}+${9}+${10}+${11}+${12}+${13}+${14}+${15}+${16}+${17}+${18}+${19}+${20}+${21}+${22}+${23}+${24}+${25}+${26})/24))
    echo $g
    Avg_list[${c}]=$g
    ((c=c+1))
done < daily.txt
```

New error:

while read -r line ; do
        v=$line
        set -- $v
        ((g=${2}+${3}+${4}+${5}+${6}+${7}+${8}+${9}+${10}+${11}+${12}+${13}+${14}+${15}+${16}+${17}+${18}+${19}+${20}+${21}+${22}+${23}+${24}+${25}+${26})/24)PerformanceAM.sh[18]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 21 : `/24' is not expected.

Thanks for your suggestions! when I tried used bracket i get this error...I'm now even more confused....it seems like it's not collecting numbers at all...

Comment: What output are you expecting? I modified your code slightly and I'm getting: `++++++++0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6
55+54+54+54+54+54+54+54+CPU0+CPU1+CPU2+CPU3+CPU4+CPU5+CPU6+CPU7+CPU8+CPU9+550+551+552+553+554+555+556
56+56+57+55+58+56+56+56+CPEAK0+CPEAK1+CPEAK2+CPEAK3+CPEAK4+CPEAK5+CPEAK6+CPEAK7+CPEAK8+CPEAK9+560+561+562+563+564+565+566`

Comment: Older ksh's may or may not support $10 as "bare" variable name, try editing as ${10}, ${11}, ... Good luck.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `(` before `$`: `((g=${2}...`, that might be the problem

Comment: @Skyte ok so Avg_list[1]= be 54 since average of 55 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 55 54 54 55 56 57 54 57 54 is 54.4

Comment: @doubleDown DOUGH! well it works now hehe i did not realized that there was extra bracket...Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read -r line ; do
    v=$line
    set -- $v
    ((g=(${2}+${3}+${4}+${5}+${6}+${7}+${8}+${9}+${10}+${11}+${12}+${13}+${14}+${15}+${16}+${17}+${18}+${19}+${20}+${21}+${22}+${23}+${24}+${25})/24))
    echo $g
    Avg_list[${c}]=$g
    ((c=c+1))
done < daily.txt
```

You were missing one `(` at `g=${2}` and the arguments only go until ${25} not ${26}.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

`while read -r line; do

    sum=0
    total=0
    for x in $line; do
        # if x is numeric
        if echo "$x" | grep -E '^[0-9]*$' > /dev/null ; then
            ((sum=sum+x))
            ((total=total+1))
        else
            echo -n "$x "
        fi
    done

    if [ $total = 0 ]; then
        echo
    else
        echo $((sum/total))
    fi

done < daily.txt`

This follows my general principle of never making long lists of $1 $2...   This solution works for any number of integers per line, and it also prints out the line label (a feature easy to remove if you want).

Answer (score 1):

For reference purposes, here's how `awk` can be used to solve this

```
array=( $(awk '{sum=0; for (i=2;i<=25; i++) sum=sum+$i; printf "%.0f ",sum/24 }' daily.txt ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of numbers, it's a little tidier to use reverse-polish notation for the calculations:

```
c=0
while read line; do
     set -- $line
     shift
     script="3 k $* + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + 24 / p"
     Avg_list[c++]=$( dc -e "$script" )
done < daily.txt
```

Then

```
printf "%s\n" "${Avg_list[@]}"
```

produces

```
54.458
57.250
94.333
94.875
```